# How to show formset from two related models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Is there a simple way of displaying a form with two related models? Consider these in the models.py file:

```
class InvoiceList(models.Model):
    invoice_number = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    recipient = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class InvoiceItem(models.Model):
    item_description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    list = models.ForeignKey(InvoiceList)
```

So basically, each invoice can have one or more invoice-items.

forms.py:

```
class InvoiceListForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = InvoiceList
        fields = ['invoice_number', 'recipient']

class InvoiceItemForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = InvoiceItem
        exclude = ('list',)
        fields = ['item_description']
```

My problem is in views.py

```
def update_edit(request, invoice_id):
    a = get_object_or_404(InvoiceList, pk=invoice_id)
    form = InvoiceListForm(instance=a)
    formset = InvoiceItemForm(instance=a)
    return render(request, 'file.html', {'invoice_info': form, 'items': formset})
```

file.html

```
<h1>Something Something Invoice</h1>

<form action="." name="stock_details" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}

{{ invoice_info.as_p }}

{% for item in items %}
    {{ item.as_table }}<br>
{% endfor %}

</form>
```

The above doesn't work fully. It displays invoice_info, but not items. I'm sure it's to do with instance calling on the wrong thing. Can anyone assist? Thank you!

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    #This view is the main page when loaded
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

    #This view is when viewing the details
    url(r'^invoice/(?P<invoice_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),

    #This view is when doing some function
    url(r'^add_new_invoice/$', views.add_new, name='add_new'),

    #This view is to delete an invoice
    url(r'^delete/(?P<invoice_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.delete, name='delete'),

    #This view is to update an invoice
    url(r'^update/(?P<invoice_id>\d+)/(?P<item_id>\d+)/$', views.update_edit, name='update_edit'),
]
```

index.html (this is where invoices are listed)

```
{% if latest_invoice_list %}
    <h1>Invoices</h1><br>

    <table border=1>
        <tr>
            <td width=50 align="center">Invoice Number</td>
            <td width=200 align="center">Recipient</td>
            <td align="center">Update/Resend</td>           
            <td align="center">Delete</td>
        </tr>

    {% for invoice in latest_invoice_list %}
        <tr>
            <td align="center">{{ invoice.invoice_number }}</td>
            <td align="center"><a href="/invoice/{{ invoice.id }}/">{{ invoice.recipient }}</a></td>
            <td align="center"><form action="{% url 'update_edit' invoice.id invoice.item_id %}" name="update" method="post" valign="bottom">{% csrf_token %}<input type="submit" value="Update"></form></td>
            <td align="center"><form action="{% url 'delete' invoice.id %}" name="delete" method="post" valign="bottom">{% csrf_token %}<input type="submit" value="Delete"></form></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <a href="{% url 'add_new' %}">Create a new invoice</a>
{% else %}
    <p>No stocks were added. <a href="{% url 'add_new' %}">Create a new invoice now!</a></p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: And yes, I do realize the views def is extremely bare. I'll fill it out with the appropriate checks once I get it basically working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I managed to solve it through the use of inlineformset_factory, but placed inside the forms.py file. So here it is in case anyone is looking for it:

forms.py

```
# Added this new line at the top
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory

# Placed this at the very bottom
InvoiceFormSet = inlineformset_factory(InvoiceList, InvoiceItem, fields=('item_description',), extra=0)
```

views.py

```
# Added this line at the top
from .forms import InvoiceFormSet

# Adjusted the def to this
def update_edit(request, invoice_id):

    # Confirm and acquire the stuff from the main model
    a = get_object_or_404(InvoiceList, pk=invoice_id)

    # Acquire the related model stuff under the main model & assign to "b"
    b = InvoiceFormSet(instance=a, prefix="item")

    # Acquire the stuff from the main model & assign to "form"
    form = InvoiceListForm(instance=a, prefix="list")

    return render(request, 'file.html', {'invoice_info': form, 'items': b})
```

file.html

```
<h1>Something Something Invoice</h1>

<form action="." name="stock_details" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}

{{ invoice_info.as_p }}

{% for item in items %}
    {{ item.as_table }}<br>
{% endfor %}

</form>
```

The "item in items" now also work, can iterate through the contents that way. Strangely, there's a "Delete" checkbox that appears on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do `{{ items.as_table }}` instead of the `for` loop you did.

Also adding a prefix since they're on the same HTML form will make data know to which form it belongs

More about prefix here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms

**Edit**

You're trying to use an instance of the `InvoiceList` model for both the `InvoiceListForm` and `InvoiceItemForm` which will not work.

Since you're editing both of them it's better to inlcude an `item_id` too in the url and then get the instance of the `InvoiceItem` from that

```
def update_edit(request, invoice_id, item_id):
    a = get_object_or_404(InvoiceList, pk=invoice_id)
    i = get_object_or_404(InvoiceItem, pk=item_id)
    form = InvoiceListForm(instance=a, prefix="list")
    formset = InvoiceItemForm(instance=i, prefix="item")
    return render(request, 'file.html', {'invoice_info': form, 'items': formset})
```

**Or** simply just include the `item_id` and then from that get the `InvoiceList` instance from the foreign key.

```
 def update_edit(request, item_id):
    i = get_object_or_404(InvoiceItem, pk=item_id)
    form = InvoiceListForm(instance=i.list, prefix="list")
    formset = InvoiceItemForm(instance=i, prefix="item")
    return render(request, 'file.html', {'invoice_info': form, 'items': formset})
```

Comment: Thanks. The contents of "items" are still empty unfortunately, but the prefixes do appear in the ids.

Comment: Thanks again @kushtrimh! The first solution doesn't work unfortunately, I'm not sure how to tweak the regex in urls to implement both invoice_id and item_id.

The second solution displays something, but it's not quite right. I had to change "invoice_id" to "item_id" in urls.py to make it work. Without that, it gives out an "unexpected keyword argument invoice_id".

After the change, it sortof reverses the display. Eg: InvoiceA(1,2,3...) & InvoiceB(1,2,3...). Viewing the first invoice in the list (id=1), shows InvoiceA(1). Viewing the second invoice in the list (id=2), shows InvoiceA(2).

Comment: For the first solution to include the `item_id` you shall make this pattern `url(r'^yourpath/(?P<invoice_id>\d+)/(?P<item_id>\d+)/$', views.update_edit, name="viewname")`

Comment: Thanks again! Well, for the first solution, it messed up the url structure in the form frontside, causing a keyword error. Typing it manually in displays something however. The same issue persists as with the second solution unfortunately. In either cases, it doesn't display the contents of the invoice fully. It there some way of keeping the original url structure, and adjusting the view instead?

Comment: Can you post the content of the link that gets you to this template?

Comment: Sure! I've edited the OP and included the urls.py & file.html.

Comment: Thank you very much @kushtrimh, but I think I solved the issue through another way. Appreciate it very much!

Comment: Sorry I wasn't there to help when you edited the question, and I'm happy that you solved it!